# Expressão não traz resultado, mas existem dados

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Essa é minha query no sql direto.

```
select c.de_cnpj, c.DT_TransacaoV from T_CRM_StatusPDV c
join T_PDV p on c.DE_CNPJ = p.CNPJ
where DATEDIFF(DAY,c.DT_TransacaoV,GETDATE()) > 45
```

Essa é minha expressão lambda, que ao meu ver é correspondente a essa query.

```
var resultado = db.T_CRM_StatusPDV
                  .Join(db.T_PDV, t1 => t1.DE_Cnpj, t2 => t2.CNPJ, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2})
                  .Where(dt => DbFunctions.DiffDays(dt.t1.DT_TransacaoV, DateTime.Now) > 45
                               && dt.t2.DataCadastro >= dataInicio
                               && dt.t1.DT_ControleV >= dataControle)
                  .Select(i => new { i.t1.DE_Cnpj }).ToList();
```

Acontece que a query me traz mais de 100 registros, e com o lambda, o `Count` traz zero.

Comment: Experimente retirar o `Select()` e o `ToList()` e atribua a expressão a uma variável, por exemplo: `var sentenca = db.T_CRM_StatusPDV.Join(db.T_PDV, t1 => t1.DE_Cnpj, t2 => t2.CNPJ, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2}).Where(dt => DbFunctions.DiffDays(dt.t1.DT_TransacaoV, DateTime.Now) > 45
 && dt.t2.DataCadastro >= dataInicio && dt.t1.DT_ControleV >= dataControle)`. Veja em debug o valor de `sentenca`. Qual o SQL gerado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o erro. Falta de atenção é fda. Existe um && tal e tal, que essa relação é que tá matando. Post resolvido. Faltou mais observação de minha parte. Isso tem que subir hoje e a pressão às vezes nos faz não olhar para o óbvio.

Comment: Publique a solução, pode vir a ajudar outrem.

Answer (score 2):

***solução:***

```
var lambda = db.T_CRM_StatusPDV
          .Join(db.T_PDV, t1 => t1.DE_Cnpj, t2 => t2.CNPJ, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2})
          .Where(dt => DbFunctions.DiffDays(dt.t1.DT_TransacaoV, DateTime.Now) > 45
                    & dt.t2.DataCadastro >= dataInicio
                    & dt.t1.DT_ControleV >= dataControle)
          .Select(i => new { i.t1.DE_Cnpj }).ToList();
```